# How can I store the data in a variable of an ajax call and print it?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have two files one with a login form, and one with the response content if the call is successful, it executes another one for loading buttons. What I would like to do is that inside the first call there is a field called RSociale and that inside has the name and surname of the user who logged in. How can I retrieve that field and print it in the part where the buttons are already there?

This is the ajax call to login:

```
function lg_controllacredenziali() {
    sem_PulisciCampiObbligatori();
    if ($('#password').hasClass("form-required") == false) {        $('#password').addClass("form-required");   }
    if ($('#password').hasClass("form-text") == false) {        $('#password').addClass("form-text");   }
    if ($('#user').val() == '') {
        sem_ControllaCampiRichiesti();
        lg_ControllaCampiText();
    }
    if ($('#user').hasClass("input-text") == true) {    $('#user').removeClass("input-text");   }
    if ($('#user').hasClass("input-user") == true) { $('#user').removeClass("input-user"); }
    if ($('#password').hasClass("input-text") == true) { $('#password').removeClass("input-text"); }
    if ($('#password').val() == '') {
        sem_ControllaCampiRichiesti();
        lg_ControllaCampiText();
    } else {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: sem_wsurl + 'ws_json_intra_logon',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                login: $('#user').val(),
                clear: 'S',
                password: encodeURI($('#password').val())
            },
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            processData: true,
            success: function(json) {
                if (json.Response[0].ResultCode != "000") {
                    lg_ControllaCampifalse();
                    if ($('#password').hasClass("input-false") == false) { $('#password').addClass("input-false"); }
                    if ($('#user').hasClass("input-false") == false) { $('#user').addClass("input-false"); }
                    if ($('#user').hasClass("input-required") == false) { $('#user').addClass("input-required"); }
                    if ($('#password').hasClass("input-required") == false) { $('#password').addClass("input-required"); }
                  } else {
          //Setto i Cookie
          sem_setCookie("wc_login",$('#user').val(),null);
          sem_setCookie("wc_password",json.Response[0].Pwdcookie,null);
          //lg_setCookie("wc_database",json.Response[0].Dbcookie,10);
          sem_setCookie("wc_database","dbeutelia",null);
          sem_setCookie("wc_header",sem_header,null);
          sem_setCookie("wc_footer",sem_footer,null);
                    window.location.replace("sem_menu.html");
                    window.open(url, "_self");
                }
            },
            error: function(error) {}
        });
    }
}
```

If the call is successful, it opens a page which in its turn makes another call to load the buttons

```
function CaricaCluster() {
    if (sem_readCookie("wc_login") != null && sem_readCookie("wc_password") != null)
    {
          if (sem_readCookie("wc_login").replace(/\"/g,"") != ''  && sem_readCookie("wc_password").replace(/\"/g,"") != '')  {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: sem_wsurl + 'ws_json_sem_cluster',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                ws_login: sem_readCookie("wc_login").replace(/\"/g,""),
                ws_password_type: 'C',
                ws_pwd: encodeURI(sem_readCookie("wc_password").replace(/\"/g,""))
            },
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            processData: true,
            success: function(json) {
                if (json.Response[0].ResultCode != "000") alert("errore");
                else {
                    $.each(json, function() {
                        TblPulsanti = json.Response[0].Details;
                        StampaPulsanti();
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert("Errore");
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: In the code you're sharing, there is no such a variable as RSociale, am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, because the variable is contained in the json file: https://intra.clouditalia.com/public/ws_json_intra_logon?login=claudia.mentuccia&clear=S&password=xxxxx

Comment: Ok, then I see two options here. Either save the RSociale in a cookie if the second page is on the same domain. Or pass the RSociale as a 'GET' parameter of the page loading process (if possible, but then you'd need to change the way you load your second page). A third possiblity (if possible, the best) is to have that in a session on the server side

Comment: I think the simplest thing to do is to save the field in a cookie. Could you give me the code that I just can't do this thing? Thanks in advance!!